# How secure is OpenCore Legacy Patcher?

Tags: macos, patching

My MacBookPro doesn't get major updates anymore, but the hardware still works well.

I came accross [OpenCore Legacy Patcher](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/), which allows to install recent versions of MacOs onto older macs through patches.

How secure is it? Is there a bigger risk of being infected and hacked with this type of software than when installing any other application?

Comment: It's open source, so you can always audit the code to determine if it's safe or not.

Comment: I am tech savvy enough to install the patch, but not enough to audit the code.

Answer (score 1):

From a relevant [Ars Technica article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/10/opencore-legacy-patcher-delivers-unofficial-ventura-support-for-older-macs/):

> Running Ventura using OCLP has risks. [...] These older Macs may also miss out on some of the security updates offered to newer models. Official macOS updates sometimes contain new system firmware and other low-level fixes that can address bugs or patch security holes; unsupported Macs running Ventura via the OCLP project won't receive these kinds of fixes.

So it does look like you may be left vulnerable to some types of attacks down the road.

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/security-for-oclp-opencore-legacy-patcher.2406586/) looks relevant to this topic.

Does this "deeveedee" know what she's talking about?  There are responses in the thread which appear to be from the OCLP software developers admitting to the security vulnerabilities in OCLP.  I'd trust them before anyone else.  It appears from the discussion that OCLP is more of a hobby than a real product.

EDIT: A quote from one of the primary OCLP developers in [this link](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/security-for-oclp-opencore-legacy-patcher.2406586/) admits to compromised security that can't be helped because of the way macOS must be patched to run on unsupported Macs: "Because of everything mentioned above (security is already compromised to begin with), updating kexts/frameworks has not been a priority for us. We will take a look to see what we can update without breaking things, but it's definitely not going to be quick."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No offense, Community Bot, but my post includes the link to the source.  Maybe Community Bot needs to be able to drill one level down to assess the quality of the post.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to the community! The bot is a real bot per se, but a fake alias for an actual person reviewing your answer in this case. You should quote some of the forum discussion posts' contents to put leverage and trust onto your answer.

Answer (score -2):

It depends

NEVER EVER try such stuff on your main device. If that MacBook you're talking about is your primary/ sole or important device, then my answer would be a big NOOO!!

But yeah, if it is lying around, and you wanna play with it, go ahead. There's no harm. Just make sure you have no Personal Data on it. Erase and install MacOS than Upgrading.

OpenCore is a group of dedicated and reputed individuals, but I don't think it truly ever has been Audited. Not saying the Developers have any bad intentions, but even genuine mistakes can leave your device vulnerable to exploitation.

Comment: This never answers the question. You don't talk about if it is "secure" and you never explain why you have your suggestions. This appears to be a collection of opinions. Can you edit the question to explain your suggestions and keep it to answering the question "is it secure?"

Comment: ...and please add sources for your facts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "The developers may have the best intentions but their code can have vulnerabilities" is a statement that is true for every piece of software ever written.